# What's the best way to get a description of the website, in Python?

Tags: python, html, string, templates, parsing

Suppose I downloaded the HTML code, and I can parse it.
How do I get the "best" description of that website, if that website does not have meta-description tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on the "Readability" suggestion above (which itself is inspired by the website InstaPaper), they have release the JavaScript: http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/. What's more, some guy took that and ported it to python: http://github.com/gfxmonk/python-readability. Rejoice!

Answer (score 3):

You could get the first few sentence returned from something like [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/).

Safari 5 uses it, so it must be alright :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to come up with a rule that works 100% of the time, obviously, but my suggestion as a starting point would be to look for the first `<h1>` tag (or `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc - the highest one you can find) then the bit of text *after* that can be used as the description. As long as the site is semantically marked-up, that should give you a good description (I guess you could also take the *contents* of the `<h1>` itself, but that's more like the "title").

It's interesting to note that Google (for example) uses a keyword-specific extract of the page contents to display as the description, rather than a static description. Not sure if that'll work for your situation, though.